# directory in isolated storage windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

i would like to create a directory in my isoalted storage and a subdirectory in this directory 
i use this method

```
private void create_directory(string directoryName)
{
    try
    {
        IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (!myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
        {
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName+"/Books");
            myIsolatedStorage.CreateDirectory(directoryName + "/EpubBooks");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // handle the exception
    }
}
```

but when i open the isolated storage explorer i Watch only the directory the two subdirectory are not created

Comment: is an exception raised?

Comment: You didn't really handle that exception, you just hid it from yourself. Try enabling CLR exceptions and running the code in debugger to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try to iterate the isolated storage with code. Your subdirs are created:

```
    private void TestDir(string directoryName)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            var myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            if (myIsolatedStorage.DirectoryExists(directoryName))
            {
                var path = string.Format("{0}\\*", directoryName);
                list = myIsolatedStorage.GetDirectoryNames(path).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }
```

Looks like there is [a bug in Isolated Storage Explorer](http://wp7explorer.codeplex.com/releases/view/61282) (see the first comment).